# Blog hecho con GOHUGO no me guarda los cambios en mi sitio de github

Tags: web, github, blogger, github-pages

Hola a todos este es mi sitio web hecho en GITHUB :p
[Mi sitio web](https://arthurcadena.github.io/programacion/)

sin embargo cuando hago cambios en mi repositorio escribiendo un articulo o de cualquier otro tipo estos no se reflejan en mi sitio estático X_X y no se si tenga mal alguna configuración es por alguna versión de HUGO que este usando, este es el sitio del framework [enalce del framework](https://gohugo.io/)

y aquí esta mi repositorio por si alguien sabe que puedo hacer al respecto de antemano muchísimas gracias :D !!
[Repositorio de mi pagina :D !!](https://github.com/ArthurCadena/programacion)

Comment: No uso ese programa, pero generalmente luego de editar el markdown debes regenerar el sitio y subir el html actualizado (con un commit al repositorio).

Comment: hice eso pero los cambios no se mostraron X_x

Comment: te aseguraste que los cambios aparezcan (y el commit) en tu [repositorio remoto](https://github.com/ArthurCadena/programacion)? veo que el ultimo commit es de hace 3 meses